# Error while inserting XML data through stored procedure

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server-2005

I have a table with the column's datatype as `xml` in SQL Server 2005. I created a stored procedure to insert values into that column.

But when calling the SP from code in C#, its giving me an error

> Failed to convert parameter value from a XDocument to a String.

Can anyone help with this?

This is the stored procedure I created:

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[TestReportRepository_Save]
@ReportExecutionTime datetime,
@ReportFile xml,

as
begin

insert into TestReportRepository(ReportExecutionTime,ReportFile) values(@ReportExecutionTime,@ReportFile)

end
```

The C# code is

```
DbParameter dbParam1 = dac.Parameter("@ReportExecutionTime", ReportExecutionTime, DbType.DateTime, ParameterDirection.Input);
DbParameter dbParam2 = dac.Parameter("@ReportFile", xmlDoc.Document, DbType.Xml, ParameterDirection.Input);

DbParameter[] dbParamColl = new DbParameter[] { dbParam1, dbParam2 };
long reportID = dac.Save("TestReportRepository_save", dbParamColl);
```

Please help me identify what I am doing wrong.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Where in your C# code are you supplying the values for the parameters?? I don't see that. Basically - the XML type of SQL Server is a glorified string - it cannot deal with an `XDocument` directly - you'll have to "serialize" that `XDocument` into a string to pass it to SQL Server (e.g. usign the `.ToString()` method)

Comment: Thanks @marc_s: I will keep your suggestion in mind while posting any new Question. Also Thanks for the solution it worked out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When passing this parameter - pass not XDocument object, but its string representation.

For XmlDocument it is XmlDocument.OuterXml, find one for XDocument and pass it

Comment: @mark_s Sorry, I've not noticed your comment when wrote the answer, if you decide that it is a rep whoring - i'll delete the answer

Comment: No worries :-) I just didn't feel like expanding this to a "real" answer - you did - you deserve the credit for your effort!

Comment: @OlegDok Useful information from your side. Thanks for the help.